# Power Apps, Drop Columns formula help

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, formula

I am trying to drop columns so I can get my browse gallery working properly.
However my formula is not working properly.

I get error:

> There is an error in this formula. Try revising the formula and running it again

Formula I am using:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    DropColumns(
    SortByColumns(
        AddColumns(
            Filter(
                [@'Documentation Tracker'],
                Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
            ),
            "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value, "ApprovalStatusValue", 'Approval Status'.Value, "AutomationTypeValue", 'Automation Type'.Value, "ApproverValue", Approver.Value
        ), 
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "ApprovalStatusValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "AutomationTypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "ApproverValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
        Ascending
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        AddColumns(
            Filter(
                [@'Documentation Tracker'],
                TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
            ),
            "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value, "ApprovalStatusValue", 'Approval Status'.Value, "AutomationTypeValue", 'Automation Type'.Value, "ApproverValue", Approver.Value
        ),
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "ApprovalStatusValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "AutomationTypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "ApproverValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
        Ascending
        ),
    "Doc_TypeValue")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula, it should work for you:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    DropColumns(
        SortByColumns(
            AddColumns(
                Filter(
                    [@'Documentation Tracker'],
                    Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
                ),
                "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value, "ApprovalStatusValue", 'Approval Status'.Value, "AutomationTypeValue", 'Automation Type'.Value, "ApproverValue", Approver.Value
            ), 
            If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "ApprovalStatusValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "AutomationTypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "ApproverValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
            Ascending
        ),
        "Doc_TypeValue", "ApprovalStatusValue", "AutomationTypeValue", "ApproverValue"
    ),
    DropColumns(
        SortByColumns(
            AddColumns(
                Filter(
                    [@'Documentation Tracker'],
                    TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
                ),
                "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value, "ApprovalStatusValue", 'Approval Status'.Value, "AutomationTypeValue", 'Automation Type'.Value, "ApproverValue", Approver.Value
            ),
            If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "ApprovalStatusValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "AutomationTypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "ApproverValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
            Ascending
        ),
        "Doc_TypeValue", "ApprovalStatusValue", "AutomationTypeValue", "ApproverValue"
    )
)
```

**Documentation**: [AddColumns, DropColumns, RenameColumns, and ShowColumns functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-table-shaping)